# Sprout Forms Confirmation Page Field Not Defined

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I'm trying to create a confirmation page for a Sprout form, where I want to check if a certain field is present, and if so, check for a value, so I can return a message based on that value.

I'm using lastEntry, and am able to pull the valid fields in without a problem, but it's having issues checking whether the field is defined. I'm currently using the following code:

```
{% set lastEntry = craft.sproutForms.lastEntry() %}
{% set qualified = true %}
{% if lastEntry.fieldName is defined and lastEntry.fieldName == 'no' %}
    {% set qualified = false %}
{% endif %}
```

When I use the code above, and the field has not been used in the particular form, I see:
`Craft\SproutForms_EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "fieldName".`

It appears Craft is seeing the field as defined, but not. Anyone have any ideas on what I could do to figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: The check for `is defined` should not be necessary. The `lastEntry` tag returns a `SproutForms_Entry` model which would define all fields that you have in your Form.  Also, your `is defined` check above could potentially return false positives in some scenarios. When you need to check `is defined` on Element attributes you'll want to use the syntax `if lastEntry['fieldName'] is defined`. (More on that issue in the Objects section here: https://straightupcraft.com/articles/how-to-check-if-a-variable-or-value-exists-using-twig).

Comment: Can you share what field type you are using in your example?

Comment: Aha. That's interesting. I'm using a drop-down field in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `lastEntry` variable on your page. You are either setting `lastEntry` to be the `SproutForms_FormEntryModel` or `null`. In both cases you are defining the variable.

```
{# Sets lastEntry to SproutForms_FormEntryModel or null #}
{% set lastEntry = craft.sproutForms.lastEntry() %}
```

If you then want to test the `lastEntry` variable, you'll need to use something different that `is defined`.

I believe the following will work:

```
{% set lastEntry = craft.sproutForms.lastEntry() %}
{% set qualified = true %}
{% if lastEntry and lastEntry.fieldName == 'no' %}
    {% set qualified = false %}
{% endif %}
```

Testing for `if lastEntry` will work just like using `if lastEntry is not null`. The secondary part of your conditional should only be evaluated if `if lastEntry` returns true, in which case your `SproutForms_FormEntryModel` would exist and the `fieldName` field would be defined, with or without a value.